# How can you use PHP to fetch data from a database using data already returned from the database?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, database

**My goal:** Use JQuery and PHP to retrieve a list of words from a MySQL database, and then use data (i.e., the id of each word in that list) outputted from that list (in the form of buttons) to pull a second list of words from the database.

JavaScript code for retrieving first list of words from database:

```
$('#myButton').click(function() {
   var myData = $('#myButton').val();
   // Pass data to PHP script w/ JQuery AJAX function
   $.post("mydata.php", { buttonID: myData }, function(data) {
      $('pageSection').append(data);
   }
   $('pageSection').empty();
});
```

PHP code to return first list of words from database (simplified to focus on important details):

```
// Connect to and select database
// Execute SQL query 
// Fetch data
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   $id = $row["id"]
   // Return output
   echo "<button class=\"entry\" value=\"$id\">" . $row["word"] . "</button>";
}
```

JavaScript code for using output from database to retrieve second list of words:

```
$('#pageSection').on('click', '.entry', function () {
   // Capture data from value property of each outputted PHP button
   var value = $('.entry').val();
   // Pass value to PHP through AJAX 
});
```

**Problem:** I expect the value for each value attribute of each button to return the corresponding id. That is, the id that corresponds to each word in the database. I don't have any problem retrieving the id. I can output it in another format, but I cannot get the right id for each value. I want to get these results:

**Expected results:**

```
<button value="id1">Word 1</button>
<button value="id2">Word 2</button>
<button value="id3">Word 3</button>
```

Instead I get this:

**Actual results:**

```
<button value="id1">Word 1</button>
<button value="id1">Word 2</button>
<button value="id1">Word 3</button>
```

**Key question:** Is there a way to return buttons generated in PHP so that the value attributes of each button recognize each unique value returned from the database?

Answer (score 1):

This is related to your jQuery, not PHP. PHP *is* actually outputting:

```
<button value="id1">Word 1</button>
<button value="id2">Word 2</button>
<button value="id3">Word 3</button>
```

However, inside your click handler `var value = $('.entry').val();` is matching *all* `.entry` elements, and `val()` is returning the value of the first of those matched elements (per [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/val)).

Instead, use `$(this)` to target the element clicked.

```
$('#pageSection').on('click', '.entry', function () {
   // Capture data from value property of each outputted PHP button
   var value = $(this).val();
   // Pass value to PHP through AJAX 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   // Return output
   echo "<button class=\"entry\" value=\".$row["id"].\">" . $row["word"] . "</button>";
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Kaushik. Using the 'this' keyword in JQuery actually did the trick.